# How to click on div which contains both elements with seleniumbase?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, css-selectors, seleniumbase

Im trying to click on a element which matchs with two conditions, but i dont know how to do it using seleniumbase/css selectors.

This is the div:

```
<div class="ses-ParticipantFixtureDetailsEsports_TeamAndScoresContainer"><div class="ses-ParticipantFixtureDetailsEsports_TeamNames"><div class="ses-ParticipantFixtureDetailsEsports_TeamWrapper "><div class="ses-ParticipantFixtureDetailsEsports_PlayingIndicator ses-ParticipantFixtureDetailsEsports_PlayingIndicatorNoTeamColour "></div><div class="ses-ParticipantFixtureDetailsEsports_Team ">Edward Gaming</div></div><div class="ses-ParticipantFixtureDetailsEsports_TeamWrapper "><div class="ses-ParticipantFixtureDetailsEsports_PlayingIndicator ses-ParticipantFixtureDetailsEsports_PlayingIndicatorNoTeamColour "></div><div class="ses-ParticipantFixtureDetailsEsports_Team ">FunPlus Phoenix</div></div></div></div>
```

I tried to do something like this, because if i try with only one team it works, but i need to match both teams:

```
driver.click(f'//div[text()="Edward GamingFunPlus Phoenix"]')
```

But I received the following error (as expected):

```
 seleniumbase.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: 
 Element {//div[text()="Edward GamingFunPlus Phoenix"]} was not present after 7 seconds!
```

I need to satisfy both conditions, the div needs to contain "FunPlus Phoenix" and "Edward Gaming" in html.